# SQL syntax as parameters for a MySQL Routine?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following MySQL routine:

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getGroupOrders`(grp INT,
                                                     ord CHAR(20),
                                                     srt CHAR(4), 
                                                     page INT, 
                                                     count INT)  
BEGIN  

  SELECT * 
    FROM `dbre`.`order_info`   
   WHERE username IN (SELECT `dbre`.`users`.`username` 
                        FROM `dbre`.`users`  
                       WHERE `dbre`.`users`.`id_group` = grp)   
ORDER BY ord srt LIMIT page,count;  

END
```

As you can see, I want to pass the ordering column and sorting as a parameters, however I get a syntax error is there a way to do this or do I have to make similar routines for each type of ordering?

Comment: ... what is the syntax error saying? line 3, line 13 or what?

Comment: the syntax error is in the `ORDER BY` line where I have the `ord` and `srt` paramters, the MySQL only says that theres an error but doesn't say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in the way you try it. 
You cannot use a variable to define the ORDER BY column an direction.

The only workaround I can think of is to create a prepared statement from a dynamically created string (where you can use the variables to specify the order by details) and then execute that prepared statement.

Here is an example of such a dynamic statement:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,393613,393642#msg-393642

Comment: I had it as a PreparedStatement, but I'm triying to use a more "routine based" approach.

Comment: @Triztian: what do you mean with "routine based" approach? You can use a prepared statement in a procedure as far as I know

Comment: Sorry, I used the incorrect words, I'm trying use MySQL routines as much as I can, meaning that I don't want any "Select" strings in the java code, just CallableStatements to a Stored Procedures like this:
`"{CALL myRoutine();}"`, I know there will be times when it can't be avoided to use prepared statements but I hopes this is not one of them.

Comment: I'm not talking about prepared statements in Java, but a prepared statement *inside* the stored procedure (as that is the only way to dynamically construct a SQL string in a stored procedure)